# excel in java, how to use one column of data to print out another?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I attached an excel file to a java excel file using jxl, but now I want to read just one column of data.

I am trying to find a certain set of values and if the value on that column of data matches my desired set of values, then I want to print out the value of another cell in the same row.

This is very complicated for me and I do not know how to do it. I wanted to find all values under 2.2 in that certain column.

Comment: try using apache poi

Comment: I tried apache poi but it just didn't work, jxl was simpler for me to download.